# FragmentStatePagerAdapter not working with large amounts of Fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentstatepageradapter

**My Problem**
I'm developing a little app to test `ViewPager` with `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. The app displays a `TextView`. The content of the `TextView` changes for each page of the `ViewPager`. If I set the maximum amount of pages to a low number, it's working fine. But I need a page for each day since the beginning of the epoch. When I set `getCount()` to `getDaysSinceEpoche()` the app stops working properly. It takes up to a minute to change a page.

**My question**
What is causing this problem?
Maybe the FragmentStatePagerAdapter is not deleting the unused Fragments?

**Edit**
The getCount() method is getting called 16 times for each swipe. Why is this happening?

**Adapter class**

```
public class CustomViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{


public CustomViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    return FirstFragment.newInstance(i, "xyz");
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return getDaysSinceEpoch();
}

public int getDaysSinceEpoch() {

    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(0); // start at EPOCH

    int days = 0;
    while (cal.getTimeInMillis() < now.getTimeInMillis()) {
        days += 1;
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1); // increment one day at a time
    }
    return days;
}
```

**Fragment class**

```
public class FirstFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

private String title;
private int page;

public static FirstFragment newInstance(int page, String title){
    FirstFragment firstFragment = new FirstFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("int", page);
    args.putString("string", title);
    firstFragment.setArguments(args);
    return firstFragment;
}

//Store instance variables based oj the arguments passed

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    page = getArguments().getInt("int", 0);
    title = getArguments().getString("string" );
}

//Inflate the View for the fragment based on xml layout

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv);
    tv.setText(page + " -- " + title);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: How long does getDaysSinceEpoch() take? And how often is getCount() called? For each swipe?

Comment: What do you mean by "How long does getDaysSinceEpoch() take?" Do you mean the amount of days it returns?

Comment: No, I asked for the duration of the execution

Comment: What is the best way to measure execution time?

Comment: getCount() is called 16 times for each swipe and when starting the app 6 times. Why is this happening?

Comment: How to measure execution time: log the value of System.currentTimeMillis() at the start and the end of the method, the difference is the execution time in millisecs. I don't know what triggers getCount() (too lazy to read the source code right now) but I know it *is* called often.This means maybe you should not call getDaysSinceEpoch() from there.

Comment: I guess it should be called only once per swipe, right? And why could calling getDaysSinceEpoch() from getCount() be a problem? It don’t see why this could be problematic

Comment: It can be a problem if it takes too long to execute (-> bad for performance). Even if it does not make your app slower, it is not necessary to have the value calculated more often than once per day. Doing things which are unnecessary means draining the battery for no reason at all.

Comment: Yep, the problem was the getDaysSinceEpoch() method. Now it's working fine. Thanks!

Comment: I thought so. Happy coding :)